# HTML/CSS - div height issue

Tags: html, css

So my footer is overlapping with the bottom bits of my div. I have included an image. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I tried to play around with the height values but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iysFN.png)

here are my values for the background div, the form div and the footer

```
.hero{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url('4.jpg');
    min-height:800px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    
}
.form{
margin: 10px 25%;
width:50%;
position: absolute; 
border:2px solid black; 
padding:20px;border-radius: 25px;
background:silver; 
opacity: 0.8;
}
.footer{
    
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:pink;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

Btw my footer is inside the div hero.. Div hero acts as the container div

here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "therapy");
  SESSION_START();
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $first= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $last= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name1']);
    $country= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
    $city= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $age= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $sql= "UPDATE `userinfo` SET `FirstName`='$first',`LastName`='$last',`Country`='$country',`City`='$city',`Age`='$age' WHERE `Username`='$username'";
    $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $_SESSION['username']= $username;
    if($result)
    {
        echo $_SESSION['message']= " You submitted ";
        header("Location: profile2.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo $_SESSION['message'] = "wrong information";
    }
  }
 
  ?>
<style>
.dp{
    border-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 200px; 
    border-color: black; height: 200px; width:200px;
overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:hidden; margin-left:35%;
}
@media (max-width:700px){
    .dp{
         float:left;
         margin-left:10%;
         height: 150px; width:150px;
    }
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="hero">
<div class="nav-bar">
<div class="nav-log">
<img src="handshake.png" style="width: 105px;
    height:100px;">
</div>
<div class="nav-links">

<ul style="margin-left:50px; display: inline;">

 <a href=""><li>HOME</li></a>
  <a href=""><li>ABOUT</li></a>
  
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn">SIGN UP</button>
</div>

</div>
<div class="form" style="margin: 10px 25%; width:50%; position: absolute; border:2px solid black; padding:20px;border-radius: 25px; background:silver; opacity: 0.8; ">

<div class="dp" style="">
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    $pic=$_SESSION['image'];
        echo "<img src='images/".$pic."' >";
    
  ?>
    </div>
<br>

  <div class="form-group">
  
  <form class="forms" method="POST" action="profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inlineFormInputGroup">Country:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">City:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Age: </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
   <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="register_btn">Submit</button>
</br>

</form>
 
    
  </div>
<div class="footer">
<center>
<div class="contact">
<p style="padding-top:10px;"> <b>FOLLOW US ON</b> </p><br><div class="social" style=" display: inline;">
<img src="fb.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
<img src="instagram.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></div>
</div>
</center>
</div>

</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i think it's because the footer is position fixed

Comment: @Sfili_81 changed that but it didnt work :(

Comment: Can you add your html code ?

Comment: @RayeesAC added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `min-height` to `900px` and remove footer `height:100px;`

```css
.hero{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url('4.jpg');
    min-height:900px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    
}
.form{
margin: 10px 25%;
width:50%;
position: absolute; 
border:2px solid black; 
padding:20px;border-radius: 25px;
background:silver; 
opacity: 0.8;
}
.footer{
    
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    background:pink;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

}
.dp{
    border-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 200px; 
    border-color: black; height: 200px; width:200px;
overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:hidden; margin-left:35%;
}
@media (max-width:700px){
    .dp{
         float:left;
         margin-left:10%;
         height: 150px; width:150px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="hero">
<div class="nav-bar">
<div class="nav-log">
<img src="handshake.png" style="width: 105px;
    height:100px;">
</div>
<div class="nav-links">

<ul style="margin-left:50px; display: inline;">

 <a href=""><li>HOME</li></a>
  <a href=""><li>ABOUT</li></a>
  
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn">SIGN UP</button>
</div>

</div>
<div class="form" style="margin: 10px 25%; width:50%; position: absolute; border:2px solid black; padding:20px;border-radius: 25px; background:silver; opacity: 0.8; ">

<div class="dp" style="">
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    $pic=$_SESSION['image'];
        echo "<img src='images/".$pic."' >";
    
  ?>
    </div>
<br>

  <div class="form-group">
  
  <form class="forms" method="POST" action="profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inlineFormInputGroup">Country:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">City:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Age: </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
   <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="register_btn">Submit</button>
</br>

</form>
 
    
  </div>
<div class="footer">
<center>
<div class="contact">
<p style="padding-top:10px;"> <b>FOLLOW US ON</b> </p><br><div class="social" style=" display: inline;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/el6wz.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkUTl.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></div>
</div>
</center>
</div>

</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is in [position fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) : *The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout*

If you want to be able to scroll enough to see the content under your footer, you need to compensate the height of your footer in the content container.

Here it could be your form, but a more generic way would be to do it on body or a container next to your footer.

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px; /* height of your footer */
  background: grey;
}

#footer{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <p>This is my container</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>this is the end of my container</p>
</div>
<div id='footer'>
  <p>this is my footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: my footer is inside the hero div. Should I make some change there?

Comment: You should check by increasing hero height  if not then may be use padding-bottom:100px; for testing.
then you can set what you require etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.form {position: relative;}

.hero {position: relative;}

.footer {position: relative;}
```

That should move your footer down and give your more information about what's causing the problem. Then you can work back from there. You can also set your footer with `position: absolute;` and use `left/right/top/bottom` and `margin-left/right/top/bottom` to adjust. Otherwise, as, mentioned, try to adjust height of container and setting `position: relative` or `absolute` on it

Answer (score 0):

The main problem over here is your position parameter mismatch in your hero and footer class. You have also not assigned a top attribute to the footer css (hence causing an overlap).

Best practice suggests that everything that isn't used as a pop up should have their div style of position to be in relative or absolute.

If you wish to have it hover around or something then you should probably use the sticky value in your position parameter for footer